# Python Json change or restructure value to new keys

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file that has been generated from transfer learning that calculates the probability, following:

```
{"str.++,C_1": {
  "C_1": 1
},
  "Var,str.replace": {
  "C_2": 1
},
"str.replace,_": {
  "str.replace": 0.8571428571428571,
  "Var": 0.14285714285714285
}}
```

that need to be changed to like following, changing the value to keys as context, rule, and probability:

```
[{
  "context": "Var,str.replace",
  "rule": "C_2",
  "prob": 1
},
{"context":"str.++,C_1",
  "rule":"C_1",
  "prob": 1
},
{"context":"str.replace,_",
  "rule":"str.replace, var"
  "prob": 0.8571428571428571, 0.14285714285714285
}]
```

I tried dumps from the original python code but it just dumps value into key.

Comment: Please edit a _minimal_ code example into your question - include imports and minimal data so this can be copy/pasted into a file and _without adding anything_ run to see the problem you're getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can easily be done using a list comprehension:

```
>>> d = {'str.++,C_1': {'C_1': 1}, 'Var,str.replace': {'C_2': 1}, 'str.replace,_': {'str.replace': 0.8571428571428571, 'Var': 0.14285714285714285}}
>>> [{"context": k, "rule": list(v.keys()), "prob": list(v.values())} for k, v in d.items()]
```

output:

```
[{'context': 'str.++,C_1', 'rule': ['C_1'], 'prob': [1]},
 {'context': 'Var,str.replace', 'rule': ['C_2'], 'prob': [1]},
 {'context': 'str.replace,_', 'rule': ['str.replace', 'Var'], 'prob': [0.8571428571428571, 0.14285714285714285]}]
```

Note that `"prob": 0.8571428571428571, 0.14285714285714285` is not a valid JSON value in your expected output. The above code correctly encodes that part as a list/array.